# Not able to declare a derived datatype pointer variable in member function itself

Tags: c++, class, variable-declaration

I am trying to create a function which will print the common elements of two Linked List. I am passing the pointers to head of both list as arguments (head1 and head2).

I also tried to declared the two pointers equal to head1 and head2 (curr1 and curr2 respectively) in member function itself so that i can perform the required operation without changing the head pointers of both list. But i am unable to do this.

class :

```
class SimilarEle {

    private: struct Node {
                int data;
                Node* next;
              };

    public: Node* head = NULL;
            void AddNode (int addData);
            bool Common_ele (Node*head1, Node*head2);

           /*
           // this declaration is valid and no error.
            Node* curr1 = NULL;
            Node* curr2 = NULL;
           */
 };
```

and function

```
bool SimilarEle :: Common_ele(Node*head1, Node*head2) {

     bool flag2 = false;
     Node* curr1 = head1, curr2 = head2;    //error occured by this declrn'
        while (curr1  != NULL) {
            while (curr2  != NULL){
                if (curr1 -> data == curr2 -> data) {
                    cout << curr1 -> data << " ";
                    flag2 = true;
                }
                curr2 = curr2 -> next;
            }
            curr1 = curr1 -> next;
            curr2 = head2;
            }
        return flag2;
    }
```

Moreover if i declare the same pointers (curr1 and curr2) in the class itself i am able to compile the program. The following is the error occured .

```
    conversion from 'SimilarEle::Node' to non-scalar type 'SimilarEle::Node' 
    requested Node curr1 = head1, curr2 = head2;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: C++ syntax gotcha: When declaring multiple pointer variables in the same statement, you must include the `*` with each one.  So you want `Node* curr1 = head1, * curr2 = head2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the variables as

```
Node* curr1 = head1, curr2 = head2;    //error occured by this declrn'
```

only curr1 gets declared as a pointer type. curr2 is actually declared as Node which comes out to be

```
Node* curr1 = head1; 
Node curr2 = head2;
```

I recommend spelling out each variable separately to increase readability. If you really want to do it in one line, you would need to do

```
Node *curr1 = head1, *curr2 = head2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you can't convert from a node* to a  node. Each pointer variable declaration needs a *.

```
Node  *curr1 = head1;
Node  *curr2 = head2;
```

OR

```
Node  *curr1 = head1, *curr2 = head2;
```

Comment: yeah it's working fine now...Thanks for replying :) but i wonder why it is invalid...

Comment: When you make a pointer you place the * on the variable name and not the DataType of your variable or object.